# JavaScript Date not adding correctly

Tags: javascript

I have a current date and have a variable i which is increment i++ but the currentDate is correct until when i=4. So I have currentDate of 8/29/2019 + 4 = 2020-05-03 which is not correct. It should be 09/01/2019 but instead it is 2020-05-03

```
 listOfEvents(daysOn: number, daysOff: number, cycles: number,startDate: Date): Date[]
{
    let totalDays: number;
    totalDays = daysOn * cycles + daysOff;
    let totalDaysList = new Array();
    let currentDate: Date;
    currentDate = new Date(this.startDate);
    currentDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    let i:number = 0;
    currentDate.setDate(startDate.getUTCDate() + i);
    let currentDateOnly: string;
    currentDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    currentDateOnly = this.datePipe.transform(currentDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    totalDaysList.push(currentDateOnly);

    for(i=1; i<totalDays; i++)
    {
         currentDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);
        currentDate.setDate(this.startDate.getUTCDate() + i);
        //currentDate.setDate(this.startDate.getDate() + i);
        currentDateOnly = this.datePipe.transform(currentDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
        totalDaysList.push(currentDateOnly);
    }
    console.log(totalDaysList);
    return totalDaysList;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you able to create a minimal setup that results in the same problem e.g. would that same happen if create something like `let startDate = new Date('2019-08-29T00:00:00'); let currentDate = new Date(startDate); currentDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0); currentDate.setDate(startDate.getUTCDate() + 4);`?

Comment: That the year becomes `2020` is strange and I can't reproduce that. But it definitely would result in the wrong Date beginning with `startDate.getUTCDate() + i`  being larger then the max date of the given month `currentDate` has at that moment, and that's expected.

Comment: try to use something else than `i` in the for loop. I mean to make sure there is scope issue with the outer `i`

Answer (score 0):

This happens because `setDate(32)` automagically overflow and increment month, as a result your loop is basically

```js
currentDate.setDate(30); // 2019-09-30
currentDate.setDate(31); // 2019-09-31 -> 2019-10-01
currentDate.setDate(32); // 2019-10-01 -> 2019-11-01
currentDate.setDate(33); // 2019-11-33 -> 2019-12-03
currentDate.setDate(34); // 2019-12-34 -> 2020-01-03
```

and each time you increment month as well.

try changing

```js
currentDate.setDate(this.startDate.getUTCDate() + i);
// to
currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1);
```

> Note that getUTCDate might not work because of timezone

Comment: While your statement with the overflow is true, it does not explain the jump from `2019-08-31` to `2020-05-03` within one step.

Comment: and why it is in `Oct` (which 10 for me, and not 5) at the `setHours` line of the screenshot

Comment: @t.niese as each time `setDate(31)` is invoked, `currentDate` is overflown, when it is called multiple times, all the value just add up to 2020.

Comment: Based on the image it starts at `2019-08-29` so it would be `currentDate.setDate(30)`, `currentDate.setDate(31)`, `currentDate.setDate(32)`, for `32` it would overlflow in August. The image shows `2019-08-29`, `2019-08-30`, `2019-08-31`, `2020-05-03`. That the overflow would happen after `2019-08-31` is expected, but that it results in `2020-05-03` is unexpected, for `i=4`. For each step after `i=4` the result would be more and more of, but it still does not explain the `2020-05-03` at `i=4`, because doing `currentDate.setDate(32)` on `2019-08-31` should result in `2019-09-01`.

Comment: oh yes, for that part, i couldn't reproduce as well, there is some missing information, maybe because of  how `this.datePipe.transform` works, @jadeite1000 better clarify this

Comment: But that part is exactly the question the OP has.